# Magento2 PWA - make live?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, pwa, pwa-studio

Little confused on this PWA stuff. Everything I've seen shows the PWA URL to be localhost like PWADevServer ready at https://magento-venia.local.pwadev:8001:

How do I make this live?

Comment: You need to use upward-js. Check out Magento's documentation on it https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/technologies/upward/reference-implementation/